# Pass an input with button Tikinter python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am new in python and It is my first code..
my GOAL is to make editable table I used two classes 
my main class's goal  is to print multiple names into a table:

```
from tkinter import *
from tabels import *

class Improved():

    def __init__(self, data):
            self.data = data
            self.root = Tk()
            self.entry = []
            self.Grid_buttom()
            self.text()
            self.root.mainloop()

    def Grid_buttom(self):
        x = ['Name', 'Last name', 'Numbers']
        for i in range(3):
            Label(self.root, text=x[i], borderwidth=1, bg='white', relief='solid', fg='Black',
                  font="Times 13 bold", height=1, width=11).grid(column=i, row=0)

        for i, item in enumerate(self.data):
            Button(self.root, text=(self.data[i][0]), command=lambda: self.Command(i), height = 1, width = 15).grid(column=0, row=i+1)
    def text(self):
        '''text infront of bottoms'''
        for i, item in enumerate(self.data):
            Label(self.root, text=self.data[i][1],borderwidth=1,bg='white',relief='solid',fg='Black',
                  font="Times 13 bold", height = 1, width = 11   ).grid(column=1, row=i+1)
            Label(self.root, text=self.data[i][2], borderwidth=1, bg='white', relief='solid', fg='Black',
                  font="Times 13 bold", height=1, width=11).grid(column=2, row=i+1)

    def Command(self,i):
        self.data[i]=inside_Tables(self.data[i])

x = [['alireza', '2', '3'], ['amir', '5', '6'], ['hossein', '8', '9'],
         ['hamidreza', 'aghamiri', '09126993613'],
         ['hamidreza', 'aghamiri', '09126993613']]  # dar daste aval size colomn ha ham neveshte shode

y = Improved(x)
```

my second class is going to edit each column of our main table by clicking on it

```
from tkinter import *

class inside_Tables():


    def __init__(self, data):
     self.data=data
     self.root=Tk()
     self.entry=[]
     self.Grid()
     self.Buttom()
     self.root.mainloop()
    def Grid(self):
        '''it defines grids Of our TK ..include our rows and columns'''
        k = 0
        for i in range(len(self.data)):
                v = StringVar(self.root, value=self.data[i])
                self.entry.append(Entry(self.root, textvariable=v))
                self.entry[k].grid(row=1, column=i)
                k = k + 1

    def Buttom(self):
        Button(self.root, text="Save", command=lambda: self.Command(),height=1, width=11).grid(row=2, column=int(len(self.data)/2)-1,sticky=NSEW)
    def Command(self):
        xx = []
        y = []
        output = []
        for i in range(len(self.entry)):
            output.append(self.entry[i].get())
        for j in range(len(self.data)):
            xx.append(output[j])
        y.append(xx)
        self.new_data=y
        self.root.destroy()
```

Problem:

when I click on each column to edit it , it always pass one column with i=4
i want to pass the right column that I clicked on it

My second problem is I want to when i click on save change main data and correct it.. 
is there any solution?

Comment: Can you create an MCVE example rather than all the code you have here? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have up-voted your question, as debugging your code helped me in a project I am personally working on and for which I was at a dead end. I hope that my answer helps you understand where you were blocked at yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a few constructive comments on your code:

1. Please make your lines of code less than 80 characters for improved readability.

   - A list can always be displayed on multiple lines. ex:

   x = [['alireza', '2', '3'], ['amir', '5', '6'], ['hossein', '8', '9'],
        ['hamidreza', 'aghamiri', '09126993613'],
        ['hamidreza', 'aghamiri', '09126993613']]  # dar daste aval size colomn ha ham neveshte shode

becomes:

> ```
> x = [
>     ['alireza', '2', '3'], 
>     ['amir', '5', '6'], 
>     ['hossein', '8', '9'], 
>     ['hamidreza', 'aghamiri', '09126993613'], 
>     ['hamidreza', 'aghamiri', '09126993613']
>     ]# dar daste aval size colomn ha ham neveshte shode
> ```

- When you are defining a widget attributes: if you hit the end of a line, just split your definitions either 1 / line for better readability or at least hit enter to start a new line of definition... in the later case, don't **width=1** but instead **width = 1** ex.:

  ```
      for i, item in enumerate(self.data):
      Button(self.root, text=(self.data[i][0]), command=lambda: self.Command(i), height = 1, width = 15).grid(column=0, row=i+1)
  ```

becomes:

```
        for i, item in enumerate(self.data):
            Button(self.root, 
                text=(self.data[i][0]), 
                command = lambda: self.Command(i), 
                height = 1, width = 15).grid(column = 0, row = i + 1)
```

It's with lambda that you are having an issue on your first problem; every time that your loop passes this to your widget:

```
                command = lambda: self.Command(i),
```

It makes it change other widgets.
To make it dynamic, use a lambda variable 'x' and assign it 'i', then pass 'x' to your self.Command: This will have all your widgets recognize it's own 'i'

```
                command = lambda x = i: self.Command(x),
```

Your other problem:

1. inside_Tables does not communicate with your main window, it changes the data in the class scope, but not in the main app which is another class.
2. I think also that your button / labels could each be represented by an other class, this would allow you to make it contain it's own data, without worrying about the rest.

I have modified your code below to make it work (there are some things that are now useless, I recommend cleaning up), now you will only need a single file, I believe your 2nd portion of code implied another file called tabels.py, which I included in the main code.

> changes: 
>   instead of **from tkinter import *** 
>   your program now uses 
>   **import tkinter as tk**
>   for better understanding of what you are doing. when using Button, or Entry in your code, now it uses tk.Button, tk.Entry, tk.Tk, and tk.StringVar so you know that they come from tkinter.
>
> classes:
>
> 1. added TableRow : this class manages each of your data entry from 'x' which contains your main data.
> 2. Improved : sanitized version, this is now your main app, I made it inherit from tk.Tk, so that the window draws when you call it.
> 3. inside_Tables : sanitized version so it communicates with your main app through master and tkinter stringvars.

If you have questions, please comment.

```
import tkinter as tk
#from tabels import * # I guess both classes were coded in different files?

class TableRow(tk.Frame):
    ''' Making each data row an object for better use of data. '''
    def __init__(self, master, i):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.data = master.data[i]

        self.command_text = tk.StringVar(value=self.data[0])
        self.label1_text = tk.StringVar(value=self.data[1])
        self.label2_text = tk.StringVar(value=self.data[2])

        self.grid()

        button = tk.Button(self, 
            #text=self.data[0], 
            textvariable=self.command_text,
            command=lambda x=i: self.Command(x),
            width=11)
        button.grid(column=0, row=0)

        label = tk.Label(self, 
            #text=self.data[1], 
            textvariable=self.label1_text,
            borderwidth = 1, bg = 'white', relief = 'solid',
            fg = 'black', font = 'times 13 bold', height = 1,
            width = 11)
        label.grid(column=1, row=0)
        label = tk.Label(self, 
            #text = self.data[2], 
            textvariable=self.label2_text,
            borderwidth = 1, bg = 'white', relief = 'solid', fg = 'black',
            font = 'times 13 bold', height = 1, width=11)
        label.grid(column=2, row=0)

    def Command(self, i):
        inside_Tables(self, i)

class Improved(tk.Tk): 
    def __init__(self, data):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.data = data
        #self.entry = [] #Not used in this class.
        #self.Grid_buttom()
        self.grid()
        #self.text()

    def grid(self):
        topframe = tk.Frame(self)
        topframe.grid()
        x = ['Name', 'Last name', 'Numbers']
        for i in x:
            tk.Label(topframe, 
                text=i, borderwidth=1, bg='white', 
                relief='solid', fg='Black',
                font="Times 13 bold", height=1, 
                width=11).grid(column=x.index(i), row=0)

        for i, item in enumerate(self.data):
            TableRow(self, i)

class inside_Tables():
    def __init__(self, master, i):
        self.master = master
        self.data=self.master.data
        self.root=tk.Tk()
        self.entry=[]
        self.Grid()
        self.Buttom()

        self.root.mainloop()
    def Grid(self):
        '''it defines grids Of our TK ..include our rows and columns'''
        k = 0
        for i in range(len(self.data)):
            v = tk.StringVar(self.root, value=self.data[i])
            self.entry.append(tk.Entry(self.root, textvariable=v))
            self.entry[k].grid(row=1, column=i)
            k = k + 1 

    def Buttom(self):
        tk.Button(self.root, 
            text="Save", command=self.Command,
            height=1, width=11).grid(row=2, column=int(len(self.data)/2)-1,
                    sticky='NSEW')
    def Command(self):
        xx = []
        #y = [] #now useless
        output = []
        for i in range(len(self.entry)):
            output.append(self.entry[i].get())
        for j in range(len(self.data)):
            xx.append(output[j])

        #y.append(xx)
        #self.new_data=y
        self.master.command_text.set(xx[0])
        self.master.label1_text.set(xx[1])
        self.master.label2_text.set(xx[2])

        self.root.destroy()

x = [ 
    ['alireza', '2', '3'], 
    ['amir', '5', '6'], 
    ['hossein', '8', '9'], 
    ['hamidreza', 'aghamiri', '09126993613'], 
    ['hamidreza', 'aghamiri', '09126993613']
    ]  # dar daste aval size colomn ha ham neveshte shode

#y = Improved(x) # Removed, included below to make program standalone.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    y = Improved(x)
    y.mainloop()
```

Comment: you don't know how much you helped me .. I'm really grateful for your helping. I don't have any teacher and I am learning python by self-study. you gave me great tricks. I will study this code and I will try to learn how did you write it. tanks

Comment: I understand you totally, as a self-student myself, sometimes it's hard to get answers to our questions, as to us they mean a lot, for others they are just silly, this is why when I am at a dead end in my projects, I stop coding and come here to see if answering a few questions, or just looking at how they were answered will inspire my work.

Comment: why did you use tk.Frame.__init__(self, master) for the first Tkinter but you didn't use it for second class? do you know a website or someplace to learn Tkinter and learn your code completely? and may you explain about this self.data = master.data[i] ? u equaled a variable with a class .. the class that is not defined..

Comment: TableRow class inherits from tk.Frame, this is why I initiated the frame, the second class inherits from tk.Tk (a window) so you will find instead tk.Tk.__init__(self), 

TableRow is a child of Improved, so I am invoking it with TableRow(self, i) < "self" being the window, "i" being the index to the data to use. self.data = master.data[i] is a pointer to the main app's data using index 'i'

Comment: The internet is a great resource; I do not like to refer just to one website for learning, I prefer searching the web when I am stuck on code and try to find something that works, learning from experiment, often refactoring my existing code as practice.

Comment: tanks a lot mate <3